# Countable dense set and basis in product spaces $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$, $[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$

Tags: general-topology

For $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ and $[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$ I know a set of sequences that are constant for almost all $n$ is dense, but how to make it countable? Changing the condition to equal $0$ for all $n > N$ for some $N$ doesn't make it countable. How to define other set? What would be the countable basis? What about $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first two use members of $\Bbb Q^{\Bbb N}$ and $(\Bbb Q\cap[0,1])^{\Bbb N}$ that are $0$ for almost all $n$. For the last just use sequences that are $0$ for almost all $n$.

Comment: Oh, this was obvious. So, for the countable basis in $[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$, family of sets $(p_{1},q_{1}){\times}{\cdots}{\times}(p_{n},q_{n}){\times}[0,1]{\times}{\cdots}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}, p_{i}, q_{i} \in \mathbb{Q}\cap{[0,1]}$ would suffice, am I right? Thank you.

Comment: @dsafdaa: Almost: you also need to allow factors of the forms $[0,q)$ and $(p,1]$ amongst the first $n$.